# function call out of scope in where clause

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, scope, where-clause, list-comprehension

I have the function `pyths`:

```
-- takes an Int and returns a list of pythagorean triples whose components 
---- are at most the given Int
pyths :: Int a => a -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
pyths n = [(x, y, z) | x <- f, y <- f, z <- f, x^2 + y^2 == z^2] 
  where f = factors n
```

I get the error that `factors` is out of scope. **How can I write this function so it's *in* scope?**

I've tried:

```
pyths n = [(x, y, z) | x <- f, y <- f, z <- f, x^2 + y^2 == z^2 where f = factors n]
```

and:

```
pyths n = [(x, y, z) | x <- f, y <- f, z <- f, x^2 + y^2 == z^2, where f = factors n]
```

But then I just get syntax errors.

---

Note:
I know this may not actually do what I intend it to do.

Comment: You can make it so that `factors` is in scope by actually defining `factors` somewhere.

Comment: It's not in the prelude, nor anywhere else in the standard library.

Comment: Side note: `Int` is not a type class, so you cannot use it in a type constraint. Perhaps you meant `Integral`, which is the type class for integral types, or just the plain type `Int` as in `Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)]`?

Comment: `Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)]` is what I should have typed. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As sepp2k said, you need to define `factors`.  In your examples you change where `f` is defined, which uses factors in its definition, but no where do you say:

```
factors x = ...
```

Since there is no `factors` function defined in the Haskell prelude or other base libraries, you must write this yourself.  The [primes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primes) package will be useful to you, I expect.

Comment: Just to be a nuisance (and for a bit of shameless self-advertising), faster generation of primes using less memory is available from [NumberSieves](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/NumberSieves) and [arithmoi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi). Both packages also provide faster factorisation, NumberSieves for numbers within a sieved range (so usually not above 10^9), arithmoi that (slower, but using less memory) and general factorisation using Montgomery curves that handles numbers with up to 50-60 digits in reasonable time.